# SQLite SUM function rounding error - android

Tags: android, sqlite, sum, rounding

Why is it that when I call a `SUM` on one of my SQLite columns, it doesnt return a precise answer? Heres what I mean:

Lets say I have 4 rows in my column to sum

```
row1      8362.82
row2     +18837.42
row3     +7294.12
row4     +73.23
___________________
         17567.59
```

Now these should add up to `17567.59` right? Well my `sum` returns `17567.6`. This may not sound like a big deal but I need accurate decimals, not rounded ones. It rounds further as the numbers get larger too. Can anyone explain a solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values as integers instead of floats.

Comment: [SQLite doesn't believe in data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), I understand it's all stored as strings ultimately.

Comment: Yes it's all stored as strings. But I think I understand what you're suggesting, where I keep the numbers without decimal and after it's added up then slide the decimal two places over? The problem is idk how to do that lol

Comment: I multiplied the intial values by 100, summed them up, then divided by 100 and got the same result `17567.6` instead of `17567.59`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same roundoff problem, except mine were rounding to integers instead of maintaining one place after the decimal point. I switched to using `total()` instead of `sum()`.

From [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

> The result of total() is always a floating point value. The result of
>   sum() is an integer value if all non-NULL inputs are integers. If any
>   input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a
>   floating point value which might be an approximation to the true sum.

This doesn't explain the issue in my case, because my column contained a mix of integer and floating-point values. But I decided to try it because of the difference, and it worked. It also sums all NULLs to 0 instead of NULL which is useful in many cases.